# sslserver using 100% cpu

Tags: linux, zombie-process, qmail

I've a qmail setup with sslserver being used to secure the pop connections. Normally it runs very well, however some instances of sslserver start taking 100% cpu and its child process qmail-pop3d process is seen as zombie. The process has to be killed to solve the prb. The sslserver version is 0.70. OS is CentOs 6.0 64 bit with 2.6.32-220 kernel. Any clues how I can debug this ?

Comment: It's a bug in sslserver.

Comment: @Gilles Can u pls provide some more details? What is this bug? Is it documented in bug database of sslserver?